# Rice Hull Usage Amount

Tags: sparge, rice-hulls

What is the general rule of thumb for how much rice hulls to use? Rice Hulls are cheap but at the same time I'd rather keep them to a minimum when I do use them.
I have an Oatmeal stout recipe that uses 1.5# of oats.  I tend to use about 0.5# of rice hulls in the mash and I've never had a problem.  Cheap insurance.

I've made wheat beers with 50/50 wheat/2 row and I have used 1# of hulls in that scenario.

Comment: I like rice hulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard one pound of rice hulls per 4 pounds of huskless grain.  It really doesn't seem to require much (by weight), since the hulls have such low density.

I probably wouldn't have added it to the oatmeal stout, but I suppose it's better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add very much. I've been using just half a pound for my beer that uses wheat, which is around 5 pounds of wheat.